# How to get class name in GetLogger and print correct class name in log4j 2

Tags: java, log4j2

I have created a wrapper for logging using log4j2. This is a customClass creating a object of  :

```
logger = LogManager.getLogger(caller);
```

The problem is I am not getting correct class name in source when I am printing LogEvent.

For eg. If `abc.java` is logging `log.info`, I need to capture `abc.java` in source instead of `customClass` name.

Comment: Your question says. "How to get class name", but your description sounds more like "How to get name of file where class is defined". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I want the class name and method name from which customlogger.info was called

Comment: AFAIU logger is only created once, so caller is only evaluated at creation time. Also can you post the code that shows what the variable caller is and where its coming from?

Comment: Yes logger is created only once in CustomLogger class.                                  
 static Class caller;   caller = Class.forName(className). I dont want to write following  line of code in every class . logger = LogManager.getLogger(caller);

Comment: Just in case there might be another way to solve the underlying issue can you please tell us **why** you are creating a wrapper class for logger?

Comment: Because if there is any change in log4j 2. We need to do changes only in one library. This wrapper is used by multiple other libraries. No code change would be needed in all the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create the `Logger` just once in your wrapper object, because it is created with a specific class name (not the one you want).

So the quick and dirty way is to call `LogManager.getLogger(caller).info(message)` on every log call, and pass the calling class as the caller. Log4J keeps a hashtable of already created Loggers so it will not create a new Logger in case one already exists for the same caller class.

However, I don't think this is optimized enough for this use case, so I would probably roll my own caching in the wrapper object using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `computeIfAbsent( )`, so that retrievals of existing Logger objects don't block others.

So my pattern would be:

```
Logger logger = loggersPerClass.get(callerClassName);
if (logger == null) {
    logger = loggersPerClass.computeIfAbsent(callerClassName, k -> LogManager.getLogger(callerClass));
}
```